# issue on realm 5.7.0 for android API Added Partial Query not reflect on cloudRealm Each time mostly after 5 minute

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-cloud

I have Realm Partial Sync Query and i Attached OrderedCollectionChangeSet to it to reflect data change but when i start app it work fine but after 5 minutes its stop Sync to RealmCloud.

Android Realm api 5.7.0
RealmCloud 3.11.0

```
    public void attachRealmAsync(String id) {
db.where(MyEntity.class)
                    .equalTo(DataContract.MyEntry.COLUMN_Id, id)
                    .findAllAsync().addChangeListener(, new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<MyEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(RealmResults<MyEntity> myEntity, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
                        Timber.d("Entity Synced"+myEntity.size());
                        realmSyncChat_db.refresh();
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: got an answer : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications   GC can remove our listener

Answer (score 0):

got an answer : realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications GC can remove our listener